# Can I use "对了" to refer to as "Correct"?

Tags: meaning

Most of the time I hear people use the word "对了" to refer to as "By the way" or "Anyway" to start talking about a new topic.

Can I use "对了" to refer to as "Correct", the same meaning as "说得对" or "没错"?

Answer (score 2):

"对了" does mean both "By the way" and "correct". For the latter, "答" is often omitted while praising someone his answer/action is correct.

Comment: In my experience, "对了" might be used to say "correct" if the answer before this one was not correct --- the "了" would then indicate a change of state or situation. Just my two cents

Comment: @RandyJosleyn Yes, when one comes up with the correct answer after several unsuccessful tries. The tone is mixed with some pleasure, compliments, and relief.

Answer (score 1):

yes.You can use"对了"  as correct.
Also you can use relevant words to express similar sense. Such as: 的确.
说的对. (narrative words) 太棒了, 优秀啊(positive words) 懂王，睿智(sarcastic words)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 是 for yes. 否 for no.

对了 is not totally equal to correct. Much more like "Yes, I got it."

Answer (score 0):

No, cause the suffix '了' changed the meaning. Use them together means 'by the way' only.

The approach of it would be '对对对' which mean 'Yes yes yes (you are right)'

Comment: How about, 对了对了对了?

Comment: 对了对了对了, in Englisn maybe equal to : "oh oh oh,.." following a question...

Comment: Actually I would use it like "OK, OK, OK" :)

Answer (score -1):

The particle 了 has a few different main usages.

1. After a verb - indicates a completed action. Note that a completed action is not the same as past tense.

吃了飯 have eaten

做了作業 have done homework

2. As a end-of-sentence particle - indicates a changed status.

他們結婚了。 They are married.

你畢業了嗎？ Have you graduated?

3. As a end-of-sentence particle - used to soften the tone of a sentence.

不要這樣做了。 Don't do it (la).

Note that 不要這樣做 sounds quite a bit harsher than 不要這樣做了.

對了。 It's correct (la).

The last example "對了" can be used idiomatically as "by the way". The context should make it sufficiently clear which usage is intended.

Answer (score -1):

“对了”可以被正确地翻译成'correct'!
"对了" can correctly be translated as "correct"!

“这就对了。”她说。
"That's correct." she said

要是我算对了的话，我应该负担得起这笔租金。
If I got my sums correct, I should be able to afford the rent.

对了 as 'by the way' would only crop up in conversations:

我们今天晚饭吃什么？  对了，冰箱里有蛋糕。
What are we going to eat for supper tonight? By the way, there's cake in the fridge.